# How to hide a block if the variable is false in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a method in which I output the variable to the view. In the view, I check if the variable is true, then show the desired block, and if it is false, then do not show the block. But for some reason this does not work for me.

```
@if($mainAlbum)
   <div class="card">
      <a href="{{route('allAlbums', ['id' => $user->id])}}"><h1 class="mt-2 mb-2" style="font-size: 0.9rem; margin-left: 5px; color: black;">Плейлисты<img src="{{asset('img/right.png')}}" width="11"> </h1></a>
      @foreach($mainAlbum as $album)
          <a href="{{route('album', ['id' => $user->id, 'album' => $album->id])}}"><img src="{{$album->cover}}" class="img-fluid"></a>    
      @endforeach
   </div>
@endif
```

and method

```
public function index($id) {
    $user = User::find($id);
    $posts = $user->profile()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(2);
    $mainVideo = $user->profileVideo()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();
    $mainAlbum = $user->profileAlbums()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1)->get();
    return view('profile.profile', compact('user', 'posts', 'mainVideo', 'mainAlbum'));
}
```

Comment: Which variable are you talking about? You are passing 4 of them to the view. Additionally the code that you provided does not check if a variable is true or not.

Comment: problem with mainVideo and mainAlbum

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `get()` always returns a collection, it does not matter if there is a album inside or not, therefore `@if($mainAlbum)` will always be truthy.

What I would do is the following:

In your controller:

```
public function index($id) {
    // switch 'find' with 'findOrFail' this way it will throw a 404 if no user is found
    $user = User::findOrFail($id);

    $posts = $user->profile()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(2);

    // use 'first' instead of 'get', so it will return a model or null instead of a collection
    $mainVideo = $user->profileVideo()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();
    $mainAlbum = $user->profileAlbums()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first();

    return view('profile.profile', compact('user', 'posts', 'mainVideo', 'mainAlbum'));
}
```

1. Instead of using `find()`, use `findOrFail()`, so the page will throw a 404 error if the user cannot be found.
2. Since you are using `limit(1)` you can use `first()` instead of `get()`, `first()` will return the model or null, `get()` will always return a collection it does not matter if it contains a model or not.

In your view:

```
@if($mainAlbum)
    <div class="card">
        <a href="{{ route('allAlbums', ['id' => $user->id]) }}">
            <h1 class="mt-2 mb-2" style="font-size: 0.9rem; margin-left: 5px; color: black;">
                Плейлисты <img src="{{ asset('img/right.png') }}" width="11">
            </h1>
        </a>
        <a href="{{ route('album', ['id' => $user->id, 'album' => $mainAlbum->id]) }}">
            <img src="{{ $mainAlbum->cover }}" class="img-fluid">
        </a>
    </div>
@endif
```

1. You can get rid of the `@foreach` since your variable will now hold the model instead of a collection
2. Your `@if` check works now since `$mainAlbum` will contain the model or null

Answer (score 0):

Before your `@if ()` in your template, add `{{ dd($mainAlbum) }}`

If you are expecting the block ***not*** to display, check that returned value is *falsy* (i.e. `null`, `false` or `0`) and not a *truthy* value like a string (i.e. `""`, `"false"`, `"null"`) or an `Object` or `Array`.

If you are expecting it to display, then make sure it is a truthy value.